# Can type never be used for generic in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I'm having some issues with TypeScript in React.

I used a generic to create an abstracted class related to Axios.
The following ESLint error occurred while using `any` type as a generic type parameter.

```
ESLint: Unexpected any. Specify a different type.(@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any)
```

ESLint recommended using the `never` type instead of `any` in the generic type.

[image]

I knew `never` as a type used to explicitly not receive parameters or return values. Is it true that it can be used instead of `any` in generic?

#### source

```
import axios, { AxiosRequestConfig, AxiosInstance, AxiosResponse } from 'axios';
import { stringify } from 'qs';
import { FilterParams } from '@src/interfaces/services/type';

type MethodType = <T = any, R = AxiosResponse<T>, D = any>(
  url: string,
  data?: D | undefined,
  config?: AxiosRequestConfig<D>,
) => Promise<R>;

class AxiosClient {
  options: AxiosRequestConfig;
  client: AxiosInstance;
  get: MethodType;
  post: MethodType;
  patch: MethodType;
  delete: MethodType;

  constructor() {
    this.options = {
      baseURL: process.env.API_ROOT || '/api/',
      withCredentials: true,
      paramsSerializer: (params: FilterParams) =>
        stringify(params, { arrayFormat: 'repeat' }),
    };
    this.client = axios.create(this.options);

    /* method redefinition */
    this.get = this.client.get;
    this.post = this.client.post;
    this.patch = this.client.patch;
    this.delete = this.client.delete;
  }
}

export default new AxiosClient();
```

Comment: Probably what you're looking for is `unknown`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[typescript-eslint documentation for this rule.](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-explicit-any/)

The hint on the rule suggests using `never` if *you do not care what type it is.* Subjectively, I don't think that's the case here.

`any` types *do* work in Typescript, and if you want `D` to be literally anything, then that is fine. This rule exists because `any` obviously has no type-safety, it's preferable to explicitly define types. In this case, I can see value in `any` here, if it fits in your organization's code style, you can consider [disabling this rule.](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/rules#disabling-rules) If it doesn't, you should consider what `D` could be - `unknown` or `string | object` might work just as well here.